# How to connect GPS to IMU?

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050, tinygps

I'm planning to connect GPS to IMU, Is't possible ? I tried my best to find an article that can help solving my curiosity.  How can i connect GPS and MPU to arduino uno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not really connecting GPS to IMU, is more like you read GPS values, read IMU values and after apply what is called a sensor fusion algorithm.

One of the most common used sensor fusion algorithms is called Kalman filter (the Extended Kalman Filter more likelly). However, if you do not have some basis on control theory you may have more trouble in applying it.

[here](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/159412.pdf) is a good example of use of this kind of sensors and fusion algorithms. It is also very commonly used in drones or autonomous vehicles.

The implementation will be specific to what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you so much ! :) But how can i connect them to arduino ?

Comment: @GeorginaPattinson it depends on your sensor models. For instance [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/746) from Adafruit uses serial ([Example tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps/direct-computer-wiring)). The most modern IMU digital combos usually use I2C/SPI interfaces ([Example of MPU9150](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mpu-9150-hookup-guide))